# Can we use MASKED (FUNCTION = random(1,100)) with MONEY datatype?

Tags: sql-server-2016

Can anyone please help me with my question?
Can we use `MASKED (FUNCTION = random(1,100))`  with `MONEY` datatype? I am sure we can use it with `INT` data type.

Comment: Have you tried using it?

Comment: Yes didn't work for me but someone said we can, so bit confused.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What was the error? I'm by no means a SQLServer expert, but without that information no one will be able to help. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Even if it does not work it will allow others to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me. I think you need to add a WITH after MASKED. I found this article on data masking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
[intTest] [int] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL,
[monTest] [money] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL
)
```